# Add Cron-Job manually to the pool

Tags: playframework, playframework-1.x

I want to do the following:

Normally you implement Play-Jobs by implementing a Class which extends the  http://www.playframework.org/documentation/api/1.2.4/play/jobs/Job.html which is added to the pool OnApplicationStart...

I want to add Cron-Jobs now at Runtime (add Tasks via GUI...) but im not sure how to implement that.

I looked into the JobsPlugin and found the following lines:

```
job.nextPlannedExecution = nextDate;
executor.schedule((Callable<V>)job, nextDate.getTime() - now.getTime(), TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
job.executor = executor;
```

Do i have to add them like that?

Is that even possible? Cause i cant find any line, where the Job itself is told, which Cron-Expression it should follow...

```
String cron = job.getClass().getAnnotation(On.class).value();
```

Is this line called from outside again after a Job-Excecution and a new `job.nextPlannedExecution` is set?

---

Ok i hope im not answering my own question now, but could this be the solution?:

I implement my own Job-Class, add a Attribute e.g. `cronExpression` and overrride the Job's

```
public void _finally() {
    super._finally();
    if (executor == JobsPlugin.executor) {
        JobsPlugin.scheduleForCRON(this);
    }
}
```

to implement my own `sheduleForCron()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looking at the source code for JobsPlugin, you should just be able to mimic what is done using the `scheduledJobs` and `executor` attributes.

If you take a look at the `onApplicationStart` method, this shows how Jobs annotated with `@On` or '@Every`are managed in the job pool.`On`uses the CRON expression and uses`scheduleForCRON`, where as`Every` uses the executor to manage the repetition.

As the `scheduledJobs` and `executor` attributes are public static, you can access and maniplulate this as much as you wish, so I would suggest reading through the source code of JobsPlugin, especially the following code, and to mimic it in your own codebase.

```
        // @On
        if (clazz.isAnnotationPresent(On.class)) {
            try {
                Job<?> job = ((Job<?>) clazz.newInstance());
                scheduledJobs.add(job);
                scheduleForCRON(job);
            } catch (InstantiationException ex) {
                throw new UnexpectedException("Cannot instanciate Job " + clazz.getName());
            } catch (IllegalAccessException ex) {
                throw new UnexpectedException("Cannot instanciate Job " + clazz.getName());
            }
        }
        // @Every
        if (clazz.isAnnotationPresent(Every.class)) {
            try {
                Job job = (Job) clazz.newInstance();
                scheduledJobs.add(job);
                String value = job.getClass().getAnnotation(Every.class).value();
                if (value.startsWith("cron.")) {
                    value = Play.configuration.getProperty(value);
                }
                value = Expression.evaluate(value, value).toString();
                if(!"never".equalsIgnoreCase(value)){
                    executor.scheduleWithFixedDelay(job, Time.parseDuration(value), Time.parseDuration(value), TimeUnit.SECONDS);
                }
            } catch (InstantiationException ex) {
                throw new UnexpectedException("Cannot instanciate Job " + clazz.getName());
            } catch (IllegalAccessException ex) {
                throw new UnexpectedException("Cannot instanciate Job " + clazz.getName());
            }
        }
```

Comment: i think the sheduledJobs are just for debugging purposes.. cause its used nowhere except printing somethin in the getStatus() method... the exectuor.sheduleWithFixedDelay() adds a periodic action and the excetuor.shedule() a single action with future-delay

Comment: so, as you can access the executor directly, then you can pretty much launch any job you want to.